# Detect if an IP Address is Hosting IP or ISP

Tags: dns, ip, lookup, country

Would like to know how to detect if an IP address belong to ISP Local Company (ADSL/Fibre Optique) or Website Hosting IP Company

Basically I'am searching some kind way to detect this

Example:

```
78.46.91.39 : Hosting IP (Hetzner DE)
85.53.191.171 : ISP IP (Orange ES)
```

I had an idea to make an array of hosting name or ISP Name but it's too much and too long searching for smart coding idea.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you thinking to use `whois` data or a paid service?

Comment: What are you using to do this? What are you intending to do with the knowledge?

Comment: i'am just using whois lookup online website , and knowledge on hosting name.. , however now more & more hosting company and difficult to know of all them , so i'am asking if there some kind header information or anything else or some kind identified value or api ... i can retrieve in php to detect isp or hosting ip